# adding a JavaScript object to multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, hashcode

I have the following JavaScripts objects:

```
var foo = {"foofoo":value};
var bar = {"barbar":value2}; //and so on
```

these objects will be added to several arrays:

```
var container = [foo, bar, baz, etc];
var container2 = [foo, bar, glob, etc]; //and so on, for lots of containers.
```

If I have a lot of objects (such as foo) that get put in these arrays, would it be advantageous to use some kind of hashcode table and store objects by some kind of UID? Or does JavaScript's passing by reference give me that feature already?

[http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable) seems to provide such a function.

Sorry but my knowledge of JavaScript is not too comprehensive.

Edit: I suppose another way to re-phrase this question more generally - is there any case in which a hash table is useful for a language (like JavaScript) that passes objects by reference?

Comment: Why not put everything in an object instead of an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript objects are always passed by reference; it is impossible to unwittingly create a copy.

You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: thank you! so that means that if I have a mathematical graph object containing an array of vertices, i can set up another array of "edge" objects (which also contain said vertices) without having to worry about memory?

Comment: Whether you need to "worry about memory" only you can decide, it is an illogical conclusion given the information presented. A *non sequiteur*.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test this by changing `container[0].foofoo` and then reading it via `container2[0].foofoo`.

It will show you that the value has changed, which means JavaScript uses object references.